# F# discriminated union enumeration using reflection instead of an enumeration

Tags: f#, f#-3.0

I am enumerating through values in some discriminated unions in F# using reflection (e.g. [How to enumerate a discriminated union in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997083/how-to-enumerate-a-discriminated-union-in-f)). I want to use the values that I got from using reflection in generating different record types that are composed from the discriminated unions that I am enumerating through but I am unsure of how to cast the type UnionCaseInfo to an actual union case. Is it possible to perform such a cast? The code below represents exactly what I am trying to do (the values in the discriminated union are different and so are the variable names). I am aware I could use enumeration but I would prefer to not to use them instead of discriminated unions.

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let GetUnionCaseName (x:'a) = 
    match FSharpValue.GetUnionFields(x, typeof<'a>) with
    | case, _ -> case.Name  

type shape =
    | Square
    | Circle
    | Triangle
    | Other

type color =
    | Black
    | Red
    | Blue
    | Green
    | White

type coloredShape = { Shape: shape; Color: color }

let shapeCases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<shape>
let colorCases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<color>

let boardOfRelevantPossibilities = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array2D.init<coloredShape> 5 3 (fun x y -> {Shape = Other; Color = Black})

let OtherShape = GetUnionCaseName(shape.Other)
let rand = Random()

for shapeCase in shapeCases do
    // Is there a way to do the following comparison this without using string comparisons
    if not (shapeCase.Name.Equals OtherShape) then
        for colorCase in colorCases do
            let mutable addedToBoard = false

            while not addedToBoard do
                let boardRowIndex = rand.Next(0,4)
                let boardColumnIndex = rand.Next(0,2)

                if boardOfRelevantPossibilities.[boardRowIndex,boardColumnIndex].Shape.Equals shape.Other then
                    addedToBoard <- true

                    // I want to utilize colorCase instead of other and shapeCase instead of black
                    boardOfRelevantPossibilities.[boardRowIndex,boardColumnIndex] <- {Shape = Other; // Shape should be determined by shapeCase instead of Other  
                        Color = White } // Color should be determined by colorCase instead of White

Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

I re-re-factored my code to the following:

```
open System
open Microsoft.FSharp.Collections
open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

let allUnionCases<'T>() =
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'T>)
    |> Array.map (fun case -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [||]) :?> 'T)

type shape =
    | Square
    | Circle
    | Triangle
    | Other

type color =
    | Black
    | Red
    | Blue
    | Green
    | White

type coloredShape = { Shape: shape; Color: color }

let shapeCases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<shape>
let colorCases = FSharpType.GetUnionCases typeof<color>

let numberOfRows = 5
let numberOfColumns = 3
let boardOfRelevantPossibilities = Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.Array2D.init<coloredShape> numberOfRows numberOfColumns (fun x y -> {Shape = Other; Color = Black})

let rand = Random()

for shapeCase in allUnionCases<shape>() do
    // No string comparison anymore
    if shapeCase <> shape.Other then
        for colorCase in allUnionCases<color>() do
            let mutable addedToBoard = false

            while not addedToBoard do
                let boardRowIndex = rand.Next(0,numberOfRows)
                let boardColumnIndex = rand.Next(0,numberOfColumns)

                if boardOfRelevantPossibilities.[boardRowIndex,boardColumnIndex].Shape.Equals shape.Other then
                    addedToBoard <- true
                    // utilizing colorCase and shapeCase to create records to fill array
                    boardOfRelevantPossibilities.[boardRowIndex,boardColumnIndex] <- {Shape = shapeCase; Color = colorCase } 


printfn "%A" boardOfRelevantPossibilities
Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

This new re-factoring incorporates reflection to enumerate through discriminated unions while allowing me to generate different record types composed of those discriminated unions. I also caught two off-by-one errors, they are fixed in the re-factored code.

Comment: What exactly is wrong with string comparison - it should work just fine?

Comment: I'd rather have done the comparison directly against shape.Other, in hindsight it really doesn't matter I guess

Comment: If you know there are no parameters, you can use `FSharpValue.MakeUnion` which might do what you want

Comment: Just cast it to `shape`: `{ Shape = FSharpValue.MakeUnion(shapeCase, [| |]) :?> shape; Color = White }`

Comment: The problem with casting that way is that the following code (when inserted into the original code I posted (which is topmost snippet of code)): `boardOfRelevantPossibilities.[boardRowIndex,boardColumnIndex] <- {Shape = FSharpValue.MakeUnion(colorCase, [| |]) :?> shape; Color = FSharpValue.MakeUnion(shapeCase, [| |]) :?> color }` actually builds and will generate the following runtime error: `System.InvalidCastException` when you run your code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*To be honest, I prefer to enumerate all union cases manually in a static method rather than create them through reflection.*

As @John said, you need one more step using [FSharpValue.MakeUnion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340309.aspx):

```
let allUnionCases<'T>() =
    FSharpType.GetUnionCases(typeof<'T>)
    |> Array.map (fun case -> FSharpValue.MakeUnion(case, [||]) :?> 'T)
```

In the `while` loop, you should use `=` instead of `Equals` and use union cases (`shape.Other`) without fully-qualified names.

```
/// Use type params for clarity; type inference should work fine without them
for shapeCase in allUnionCases<shape>() do
    for colorCase in allUnionCases<color>() do
        let mutable addedToBoard = false
        while not addedToBoard do
            let r = rand.Next(0,4)
            let c = rand.Next(0,2)
            if boardOfRelevantPossibilities.[r, c].Shape = Other then
                addedToBoard <- true
                boardOfRelevantPossibilities.[r, c] <- { Shape = shapeCase; 
                                                         Color = colorCase }
```