# Enumerating a discriminated union

Tags: f#

I have read the answers from [How to enumerate a discriminated union in F#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6997083/how-to-enumerate-a-discriminated-union-in-f)

And I like the solution suggested: [solution](https://gist.github.com/smoothdeveloper/350cab95490d4b729c8b)

However, I am not sure how to write a function where I would pass the discriminated union as argument?

```
let testDisUnion a =
    SimpleUnionCaseInfoReflection.AllCases<a> 
    |> Seq.iter (fun (_, instance) -> printfn "name: %s" instance)
```

Thank you

Comment: If you want to pass the type itself (as opposed to an instance), use an angle-bracketed type argument: ``let testDisUnion<'a> = …``

Comment: @dumetrulo Thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how to use a type argument as dumetrulo suggested:

```
let testDisUnion<'a> =
    SimpleUnionCaseInfoReflection.AllCases<'a> 
    |> Seq.iter (fun (_, instance) -> printfn "name: %A" instance)

testDisUnion<MyType>
//name: A
//name: B

type MyType = A | B
```

The type argument `<'a>` is being passed from your "function" to the `AllCases` "function". I write function in quotes because although there are no proper parameters, the type argument is a type of input to the function, which means that the value is only evaluated when you "call" it with a type argument.